# Using Group_by to get the total count of each object - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is a tough problem but I'm going to be as descriptive as possible. My app has `Events` and they have many `Purchases` and they have many `Tickets` and they have one `Ticket_type`. I'm trying to get the total count of each `ticket_type` purchased on an event. My current attempt is to group the the purchases by tickets. That gets me somewhere but I really don't know where to go from there. Here is my code

```
def ticket_type_purchases
  event.purchases.group_by(&:tickets)
end

The produces this:

{[#<Ticket:0x007fb43aacdf78 id: 400, attendee_id: 436, ticket_type_id: 29, purchase_id: 10>,
  #<Ticket:0x007fb43aacde38 id: 401, attendee_id: 437, ticket_type_id: 29, purchase_id: 10>]=>
  [#<Purchase:0x007fb431bb3388
    id: 10,
    coupon_id: nil,
    event_id: 51,
    discount: 0,
    stripe_transaction_id: "ch_1A0azuG8Z38E1yTozmbRtRKm",
    purchaser_email: "cam@example.com",
    fees: 307,
    rsvp_id: 412,
    subtotal: 2000,
    total: 2307>],
 [#<Ticket:0x007fb431edae80 id: 407, attendee_id: 443, ticket_type_id: 29, purchase_id: 11>,
  #<Ticket:0x007fb431edad40 id: 408, attendee_id: 444, ticket_type_id: 29, purchase_id: 11>,
  #<Ticket:0x007fb431edac00 id: 409, attendee_id: 445, ticket_type_id: 29, purchase_id: 11>]=>
  [#<Purchase:0x007fb431bb2bb8
    id: 11,
    coupon_id: nil,
    event_id: 51,
    discount: 0,
    stripe_transaction_id: "ch_1A0bg8G8Z38E1yTovTTvfne6",
    purchaser_email: "cam@example.com",
    fees: 461,
    rsvp_id: 415,
    subtotal: 3000,
    total: 3461>],
 [#<Ticket:0x007fb43a33b9e0 id: 415, attendee_id: 451, ticket_type_id: 29, purchase_id: 12>,
  #<Ticket:0x007fb43a33b8a0 id: 416, attendee_id: 452, ticket_type_id: 29, purchase_id: 12>,
  #<Ticket:0x007fb43a33b760 id: 417, attendee_id: 453, ticket_type_id: 29, purchase_id: 12>,
  #<Ticket:0x007fb43a33b620 id: 418, attendee_id: 454, ticket_type_id: 29, purchase_id: 12>,
  #<Ticket:0x007fb43a33b4e0 id: 419, attendee_id: 455, ticket_type_id: 29, purchase_id: 12>]=>
  [#<Purchase:0x007fb431bb23e8
    id: 12,
    coupon_id: nil,
    event_id: 51,
    discount: 0,
    stripe_transaction_id: "ch_1A0d9eG8Z38E1yTou7fffFOg",
    purchaser_email: "cam@example.com",
    fees: 768,
    rsvp_id: 417,
    subtotal: 5000,
    total: 5768>],
 [#<Ticket:0x007fb43a4db610 id: 423, attendee_id: 459, ticket_type_id: 33, purchase_id: 13>,
  #<Ticket:0x007fb43a4db4d0 id: 424, attendee_id: 460, ticket_type_id: 33, purchase_id: 13>,
```

### Models:

## event:

```
 has_many :ticket_types, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :purchases, dependent: :destroy
```

## purchase:

```
belongs_to :event
has_many :tickets
```

## Ticket_type:

```
 belongs_to :event
```

## Ticket:

```
 belongs_to :ticket_type
 belongs_to :purchase
```

So, I have each purchase and you can see the attributes of the ticket I have access to the ticket_type_id. To recap, I want to get a total count for each ticket_type purchased on an event. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try this `event.purchases.group_by(&:tickets).count.sort`

Comment: Let me know if you get success or not

Comment: Thanks for the help. But, I got this error `NoMethodError: undefined method sort for 4:Fixnum`

Comment: than remove sort try `event.purchases.group_by(&:tickets).count`

Comment: That works I get a count of 4. but I don't need the count of purchases on event. I need a count of total tickets purchases for each `ticket_type`

Comment: Can you please add your three model?

Comment: @ashvin update. Thanks

Comment: ticket belongs_to :ticket_type, so your ticket_types has_many tickets?

Comment: Nope. Nothing on the ticket_type modal mentions ticket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this association to `Event`:

```
has_many :tickets, through: :purchases
```

This will help you get `event.tickets` as all tickets of this event.

Then use this to get `ticket_type` based counts:

```
event.tickets.group(:ticket_type).count
```

This will return a hash with key as ticket type and value as count of tickets of this ticket type in this event.

**UPDATE:**
To just get hash with ticket_id => count :

```
event.tickets.group(:ticket_type_id).count
```

Comment: This is close. But, this returns the full ticket_type object. not a count of each purchased.

Comment: Wait it did return a count. nvm. Thanks

Comment: I'm getting this object returns: id: 33,  ```id: 33,
  event_id: 51,
  name: "Free",
  amount: #<BigDecimal:7f9939f44e60,'0.2E2',9(18)>,
  created_at: Fri, 24 Mar 2017 16:18:26 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Fri, 24 Mar 2017 16:18:26 UTC +00:00,
  active: true,
  description: nil>=>3}``` You can see the count 3 at the bottom. How to I just pull that out.

Comment: try this: event.tickets.group(:ticket_type_id).count if you have ticket_type_id as accessible from ticket model